# Arduino : Finding ADC & Pin Change in same pin

Tags: arduino

I am using ATMega 328. I'd like to get ADC & Pin change interrupt in analog input pins (A0 - A5). ADC is working but how to make the electronic circuit for Pin change?

Comment: Are you asking how to use the same physical pin for both ADC and for digital I/O? If that's the case, not possible due to multiplexing. Otherwise, kindly clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

Some MCU from Atmel have an embedded analog comparator.
The purpose of this module is to detect the sign of the voltage diff present between the + input and the - input.

With the analog comparator enabled, you can put its threshold at Vcc/2 for instance and you will get an interrupt when the analog voltage passes below or above the threshold.

Usually, the analog inputs are multiplexed with the analog comparator.
I am not 100% sure that you can enable the ADC and the analog comparator at the same time on the same pin. It's something you will have to check in the MCU datasheet.

In any case, it's not needed to be able to enable both at the same time. If you have your ADC running, you can check the voltage level returned from you ADC in your code and trigger a soft interrupt if the voltage passe above of below you defined threshold. Using this approach, you can easily implement a shmitt trigger also.

The analog comparator is useful only if you want to stop your ADC.

Comment: @Gustavo Litovsky & Blup1980 : Thank you.

Comment: If it solved your issue, you can click to accept the answer... ;-)

Comment: The idea is to trigger backup during power failure. As learned the same physical pin which does ADC (A0) can be used to sense the HIGH LOW status on the pin. HIGH is 3V and LOW is 2V. Instead of running ADC forever, wouldn't it be effiecient if ADC done at demand... Pls do correct me if I am wrong. Had just seen this http://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/how-to-derive-the-summing-amplifier-transfer-function/

Comment: This is the purpose of the analog comparator. You set a threshold, enable it and forget. You will get an interrupt when the threshold is passed. You can then enable your ADC to check the actual voltage value, if required.

Comment: I searched for it and useful. Thanks. I've 5 ADC's to compare. So think it needs simple external circuit.